# Is my Connected Node a Glass or a Watch?

Tags: android, google-glass, wear-os, google-api-client, google-client

I am currently working on a use case wherein i need to find if my watch is paired/connected with my phone, so that my phone application is able to send the notification data to wear. 
If it is connected, then phone will send the notification data to wear or else, it will pop up some toast or anything notifying user that watch is not connected.
Currently, i am using NodeAPI to see the connected nodes. But, it could be possible that connected Node is my Glass and not the watch. How would i differ between the two? 
 
PS, Is there a generic way to identify a node as watch or glass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be an issue for you at the moment since Glass does not support NodeAPI.

Please refer to my answer to your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547106/how-does-nodeapi-in-google-play-services-work).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i am beginner with glass though i have experience on watch development.